# How can I plan server hardware capacity for a project

Tags: linux, windows, hardware, capacity

I want to learn that how How can I plan server hardware capacity by a project. But I need scientifically and    provable solution for this planning.

For example I have a project. That has 1000 unique users, 20 database tables, Used java programming language, etc. These are parameters of projects. But my process may be long running or database selection response. So I will use these parameters and get a result like this: You need 4 Core 2.4 Ghz CPU, 8GB Ram, 100Gb hdd etc.

Is there any way to do this plan?

Comment: By the way, that server hardware is lower-spec than some phones.

Comment: The parameters for the project depend entirely on the whole codebase of the project, the database schema etc. There isn't a way to just calculate it from the number of users or the number of tables or language used. That is why you need to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the proper way is performance testing.

That way you can know what resources you require for example if you have 100 users and you can multiply it for situations with thousands of users.